# Image aligning in divs

Tags: css, image, html, alignment

I'm in the process of creating a header section for a webapp. I'm having some difficulty aligning and positioning things the way it should.[image]

The logout button you see there on the right should move up into the light grey area. So in other words, in the same lign as the logo. This is the html for that section:

```
<div>

    <img src="Images/logo.png" id="imgLogo" alt="" />
    <img src="Images/logout-idle.png"
         alt=""
         id="imgLogout"
         onmouseover="this.src='Images/logout-hover.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='Images/logout-idle.png'"
         onmousedown="this.src='Images/logout-down.png'"
         />

</div>
```

The CSS for these elements:

```
#imgLogo{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#imgLogout{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to get that darn logout button to move more to the top?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that you could replace the javascript code for the logout button by a few short css rules which would separate content from style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the

```
 #imgLogout{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

to

```
 #imgLogout{
     position: absolute;
     top: 4px;
     right: 10px
     }
```

this will put it where you want it.

Comment: This solution fit in nicely in my code with minimal changes. Very nice, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For the img logo, I would make an div element and have that as a background so like:

```
#imglogo{
    background: url('Images/logo.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Then for the log out button I would put that inside the div like so:

```
<div id="imglogo">
<img src="Images/logout-idle.png"
     alt=""
     id="imgLogout"
     onmouseover="this.src='Images/logout-hover.png'"
     onmouseout="this.src='Images/logout-idle.png'"
     onmousedown="this.src='Images/logout-down.png'"
     />
</div>
```

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

You should set width for each element. Second img should has

```
display: block
```

as well.

Or you could use something like this

```
#imgLogout{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


#imgbg {

    background-image: url(Images/logo.png);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}




<div id="imgbg">
    <img src="Images/logout-idle.png"
         alt=""
         id="imgLogout"
         onmouseover="this.src='Images/logout-hover.png'"
         onmouseout="this.src='Images/logout-idle.png'"
         onmousedown="this.src='Images/logout-down.png'"
         />
</div>
```

Comment: But if I set a width for each element. Sure they'll both fit in the same line. But then the logo won't be centered in the browser window anymore right?

Comment: Right. You need different approach. Create div and use image-background and image-position to set image in the middle and put another div in it with float right. That should do the trick.